# How to say that $x+y \in \{5,7,11,17,22 \}$ in linear programming language?

Tags: linear-programming

Title says it all. I considered the use of the big-M method for inequalities, where out of $N$ constraints, if you want to choose one of the form $f_i(x) \leq 0$ you do $f_i(x) \leq M_i (1-\delta_i)$, where $M_i$ is large enough so there are no binding constraints, but then I would have to do 10 inequalities, which seems excessive. Is there an easier way?

Comment: The question should be clear without the title, compare https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/42969

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By adding binary variables $b_i \in \{0, 1\}$ for each $i \in C = \{5,7, \ldots, 22\}$, you could use a SOS1-Constraint:

$$
\begin{align}
x + y &= \sum_{i \in C} i \cdot b_i \tag{1} \\
\sum_{i \in C} b_i &= 1 \tag{2}
\end{align}
$$